# AngularJS E2E tests errors

Tags: angularjs, npm, installation, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm following the **AngularJS tutorial** found https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial.

Everything was working fine until the **E2E tests part**: running '*npm run protractor*', I get an **error**

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

I've already tried deleting the cache, *node_modules* and *package-lock.json*.

**Complete log** here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_gW1ArtS0VbGgHOE2F2X-ncvAxxQ9GDh/view?usp=sharing

### _____Edition on 10/27/18: complete log pasted________

Since some people cannot open the log, I will post it here:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'protractor' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.9.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'preprotractor', 'protractor', 'postprotractor' ]
5 info lifecycle angular-phonecat@0.0.0~preprotractor: angular-phonecat@0.0.0
6 verbose lifecycle angular-phonecat@0.0.0~preprotractor: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle angular-phonecat@0.0.0~preprotractor: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\angular-js-tutorial\angular-phonecat\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\ActiveTcl\bin;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\ffmpeg\bin;C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom\bin;C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin
8 verbose lifecycle angular-phonecat@0.0.0~preprotractor: CWD: C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\angular-js-tutorial\angular-phonecat
9 silly lifecycle angular-phonecat@0.0.0~preprotractor: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run update-webdriver' ]
10 silly lifecycle angular-phonecat@0.0.0~preprotractor: Returned: code: 0  signal: null
11 info lifecycle angular-phonecat@0.0.0~protractor: angular-phonecat@0.0.0
12 verbose lifecycle angular-phonecat@0.0.0~protractor: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
13 verbose lifecycle angular-phonecat@0.0.0~protractor: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\angular-js-tutorial\angular-phonecat\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\ActiveTcl\bin;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\ffmpeg\bin;C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom\bin;C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin
14 verbose lifecycle angular-phonecat@0.0.0~protractor: CWD: C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\angular-js-tutorial\angular-phonecat
15 silly lifecycle angular-phonecat@0.0.0~protractor: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js' ]
16 silly lifecycle angular-phonecat@0.0.0~protractor: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
17 info lifecycle angular-phonecat@0.0.0~protractor: Failed to exec protractor script
18 verbose stack Error: angular-phonecat@0.0.0 protractor: `protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js`
18 verbose stack Exit status 1
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
18 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
18 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
18 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
18 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
19 verbose pkgid angular-phonecat@0.0.0
20 verbose cwd C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\angular-js-tutorial\angular-phonecat
21 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
22 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "protractor"
23 verbose node v8.9.4
24 verbose npm  v5.6.0
25 error code ELIFECYCLE
26 error errno 1
27 error angular-phonecat@0.0.0 protractor: `protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js`
27 error Exit status 1
28 error Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 protractor script.
28 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
29 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: I can't open the complete log.

Comment: @yong I just pasted the log. Thanks for that! I cannot wrap my head around this!

Comment: I succeed to execute `npm run protractor` with following steps: 1)  execute `npm start` 2) execute `npm run protractor` in another cmd window.  If you still  fail ever follow my steps. Please show the log of running `node_modules\.bin\protractor e2e-tests\protractor.conf.js`